# Upgrading AngularJS with Rails 5.1 Using Asset Pipeline with Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular, asset-pipeline, webpacker

I have been searching for a solution and have yet to find a good strategy.

I have a giant AngularJS 1.x app that uses the Rails asset pipeline, and my goal is to use the UpgradeModule to slowly migrate from angular 1.x to 5.x using Webpacker.

My issue is... how do I get my old javascript files using sprockets and the asset pipeline to play nice with the new Webpack style of importing for Angular 5?

I could put everything into Webpack, but that would take a ton of refactoring. Has anyone had any experience with this and have a good solution?

Comment: This has been sitting here for a long time. I ended up just putting all my js files into webpack to avoid the headache.